# How do I operate a QByteArray object without copy it?

Tags: c++, qt

```
bool processData(const QByteArray & data)
{
    QStringRef qf(data);
    QList<QStringRef> splitted = qf.slit(",")
}
```

Think about there is a large block of data in the QByteArray. I want to do search, analyze it and copy a small part of it to QString. How can I do this without copy it?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Qt document](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html):

> QByteArray can be used to store both raw bytes (including '\0's) and
>   traditional 8-bit '\0'-terminated strings. Using QByteArray is much
>   more convenient than using const char *. Behind the scenes, it always
>   ensures that the data is followed by a '\0' terminator, and uses
>   implicit sharing (**copy-on-write**) to reduce memory usage and **avoid**
>   **needless copying of data**.

So you don't have to worry about the copying expense if you really don't modify the data.

```
bool processFundRankData(const QByteArray & data)
{
    int firstIndexOfCR = data.indexOf(`\r`);
    QByteArray firstFour = data.left(4);
}
```

Actually, [QByteArray](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html) has the most of "string" operation just like [QString](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html). So, no need to assign it to a [QString](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html) or [QStringRef](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstringref.html).